# When using SKPhysicsBody and contactDelegate, how do I recognize when bodyA hits a specific side of the frame?

Tags: sprite-kit, contacts

I'm trying to make a *[Pong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pong)* game. Therefore, I need to know when the ball hits the top and bottom of the frame. So I make a border whose edges is the same as the frame, and I created the function which recognizes contact (didBegin).

```
let border = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
self.physicsBody = border


func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let bodyAName = contact.bodyA.node?.name
    let bodyBName = contact.bodyB.node?.name

    print(bodyAName)
    print(bodyBName)
}
```

But the top and bottom of the frame doesn't have a name! So how can I do it?

Comment: What is the point of printing the name of those nodes? Anyways, if it doesn't have a name, give it one :)

Comment: Also if you want to detect different parts of the frame, make it with multiple bodies or edges and assign different categories to them. See what else inits SKPhysicsBody has

Answer (score 1):

`SKPhysicsContact`  contain a property called [contactPoint](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skphysicscontact)

This property show the (`CGPoint`) contact point between the two physics bodies, in scene coordinates.

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    point = contact.contactPoint
    ...
}
```

If your **TOP** and **BOTTOM** are for example:

```
// suppose myField is your playing field
let myFrame = myField.frame
// height should be the thickness of your side 
let top = CGRect(x:0, y:myFrame.size.height,width:myFrame.size.width,height:1) 
let bottom = CGRect(x:0, y:0,width:myFrame.size.width,height:1)
```

You could use also this function (the old [CGRectContainsPoint()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgrect/1456316-contains))

```
if top.contains(point) {
   // the ball touch the top side
}
```

---

If you don't want to calculate top and bottom sides, you could use also this function:

```
func getDistance(p1:CGPoint,p2:CGPoint)->CGFloat {
    let xDist = (p2.x - p1.x)
    let yDist = (p2.y - p1.y)
    return CGFloat(sqrt((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist)))
}
```

and you can check the shortest distance between contactPoint and your side as:

```
let myFrame = myField.frame
let dTop = getDistance(p1:contactPoint,p2:CGPoint(x:contactPoint.x,y:myFrame.maxY)
let dBottom = getDistance(p1:contactPoint,p2:CGPoint(x:contactPoint.x,y:myFrame.minY)

if dTop<dBottom {
    // ball is near top
} else { ... }
```

With few conditions you know exactly where is your ball.

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your ball and the edge a physics category and set its collision and contact masks. Create an enum like this

```
enum PhysicsCategory {
    static let worldBorder: UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
    static let ball: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
}
```

Thank give your nodes those categories and also set up the contact and collision masks.

```
 self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.worldBorder
 self.physicsBody?.contactBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ball
 self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ball

 ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ball
 // Set collision and contact if needed as well. Its usually fine to do it for 1 body only if they are the same.
```

Than you can write the contact method like this

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
    let secondBody: SKPhysicsBody

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    // World border hit ball or ball hit worldBorder
    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.worldBorder) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.ball) {

        // Do something
    }
}
```

Hope this helps